# How to manage different API calls on android app

Tags: android, api

I am working on school project consuming API calls. My API currently has 3 end point. There is a campus end point which list three campus (location), each campus has a list of departments. The final end point list the courses in each department.

```
//course.json?dept_abbr=MES


{
               Course: [
                  {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "CourseTitle": "..",
                    "CourseNumber": 100
                    "Quarter": "autumn",
                    "DeptAbbreviation": "MES"   
                    },
              ]

   }


//department.json/?campus=Ca
    {
               Depts[
                  {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "DeptFullName": "Math and Engineering"
                    "DeptAbbreviation": "MES"   
                    },
              ]

   }
```

I wanted to have a form where the user able to choose different courses. The problem is I need to make API call to get the campus, based on the campus
I make another api call to get a list of departments, if a user choose a particular department then I need to make API call to get course under that 
department. For example, there are around 90 departments and each departments has around 50 courses.

Do I need to store all the API responses in a server even before app launch and use those responses in the server? While preparing this question I have looked volley and Retrofit libraries. I am still looking the libraries.

Comment: I don't see any reason you'd need a server, just make the calls using Retrofit.

Comment: server I meant like a database where I store API results. Retrofit, I have been looking at it how simple it makes requests with parameters. Caching part confusing me. How does Retrofit help me? Is it with caching? Now looking OkHttp I am confused what each is doing.

Comment: Retrofit is built on top of OkHttp.  OkHttp handles the lower level HTTP stuff, while Retrofit manages the API you're interfacing with.  Retrofit allows you to define an interface that represents the API, and one or more model classes that represent the API's responses, and then you can just use the API by making method calls, without worrying about the HTTP stuff.  You could use a local database to cache the responses if you want to improve response time but it shouldn't be necessary.  I believe there is also caching functionality with Retrofit but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @nasch thank you for the input, but with search functionality in my app and calling API each time the user select one select field "department" is unnecessary. That is what I want to solve. Database or caching. I am not familiar with either.